# Starting a daemon automatically from init.d

Tags: centos, boot, startup, init.d

I installed vnstats to see bandwidth statistics, I copied an init.d file tempalte, I placed it in init.d directory, it works ok to access this file and do start/restart/status, but this file should start automatically on system boot, correct? It doesn't start, how can I debug this?
If after system boot I do init.d/vnstat then it starts.

I am running Centos 5

Thank you.

Comment: most topics mention chkconfig but: "chkconfig: command not found" maybe there is another way ?!

Comment: Obvious question, have you got chkconfig package installed? Is it in your $PATH environment variable? If you're desperate you can always drop it in rc.local, http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/rc-local-does-not-work-centos-741197/ else setup symlinks manually but obviously chkconfig is the more 'proper way' of doing things.

Comment: Found it installed in /sbin/chkconfig , thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write an init script with [the correct syntax](http://www.philchen.com/2007/06/04/quick-and-dirty-how-to-write-and-init-script), you can turn it into a service:

`chkconfig --add vnstats`

after that, you can turn it on or off for certain runlevels:

`chkconfig --level 345 vnstats on`

You can also manually start or stop services with the service command, using the functions declared in the script itself. For example, if your script has a function called stop and one called start, you can use

`service vnstats stop` and `service vnstats start`

Suggested reading: the [official documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html)

Comment: bash: chkconfig: command not found. Should the files in init.d start automatically? Is there another way ?

Comment: I would expect it to be installed by default, what is the result of running yum info chkconfig

Comment: Yum said chkconfig WAS installed, so I found it in /sbin/chkconfig and I had to use full path when calling the above instructions: /sbin/chkconfig --add vnstat

Comment: I have a question tough. Even before the chkconfig --add I seen the service "vnstatd" stopped with --status-all, I am not sure if the -add command should contain vnstat or vnstatd, should it match the file name inside /etc/init.d/ folder? I added it with "--add vnstat" and the service status refers to it as "vnstatd". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the init.d has a chkconfig setting, they you can `chkconfig --add vnstat; chkconfig vnstat on`

Answer (score 0):

You should really follow earlier suggestions of adding a chkconfig section to your initfile, but if you're lazy and want to work around this, you can just symlink the file yourself like this:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/vnstat /etc/rc3.d/S90vnstat
```

If you want to pursue the chkconfig path and lack the chkconfig package, install it with: `yum install chkconfig`